# Continuous function and extreme value theorem.

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity

Suppose $f(x)$ is a continued function defined on $[-1,1]$ with $f(0)>0$ and $f(\pm 1)=0$. Prove that there exist constants $a>0$ and $b$ such that $g(x)=-a\vert x\vert +b\geq f(x) (-1\leq x \leq 1)$, and for which there exists $c\in (-1,1)$ such that $g(c)=f(c)$.

I don't have a clue about how to solve this problem. The book gives a hint that tells me to use the extreme value theorem, and I don't know how to make use of it. And it seems that if I want to use contradiction I would have to construct a very complicated negation.

Answer (score 1):

Pick $a$ s.t. $0 < a < f(0)$ (for example $\dfrac{f(0)}{2}$ will do).

Let $h(x) = a\vert x\vert+ f(x)$. Since $h$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ and $h(1) = h(-1) = a < h(0) = f(0)$, it has a maximum $c$ strictly inside the interval, so $c$ is in $(-1,1)$.

Then if $b = h(c)$, you get your $g(x) = -a\vert x\vert + b, g(c) = f(c)$ and $g(x) \geq f(x)$ since $f(x) - g(x) = h(x) - h(c)$ and $c$ is the maximum of $h$ by definition.

Comment: One more thing... How did you come up with this $h(x)$?

Comment: The problem asks for a and b s.t. f(x) + a*abs(x) <= b, under some conditions ( a > 0, the existence of c s.t etc); so it is natural to put h(x) precisely that, let c a point where it attains its maximum (by continuity) on [-1, 1] and look at constraints on a s.t. c is in (-1,1)

Answer (score -1):

Because $[-1,1]$ is compact, $f$ has a max, suppose k and note that $k>0$ because exist a point (0) where f is positive. If we put $b=k+1$ and $a=1$ is easy check that works. The second item is not necessary true...

Comment: Uh, it may be that my statement is not clear. He meant there exists a function $g(x)$ satisfying both requirements, $g(x)\geq f(x)$ and $\exists c\in (-1,1)$ such that $f(c)=g(c)$.